# Google sheets - Count if column A text includes keywords from column B AND C

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheets, I have three columns (as set out below) each cell in column A has a block of text in. Column B is a set of keywords on coronavirus and column C is a set of keywords around data.

My goal is to find how many blocks of text talk about coronavirus statistics. I want to do that by counting how many cells in column A (text) contain any keyword from column B (coronavirus keywords) AND any keyword from column C (data keywords).

| text | coronavirus keywords | data keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yadda Yadda coronavirus yadda statistics | coronavirus | data |
| Yadda covid yadda | covid | statistics |
| Yadda covid statistics yadda yadda | COVID-19 | stats |
| yadda yadda yadda | virus | trends |
| yadda yadda yadda yadda | illness |  |
| COVID-19 trends yadda yadda |  |  |
| covid yadda yadda stats |  |  |

I've been trying with:

=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,B:B,A:A,C:C)))

Which produces an answer but I know it's wrong - it comes out as '1' but I know there's at least 5 matches.

Is there a way I can get this count?

Sorry, I can't share the actual sheets - work info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an 'AND' function between the two lists of keywords is required (and possibly case insensitive match), I suggest

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B))*REGEXMATCH(A:A, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:C)))))
```

Comment: I don't think this version worked for AND two lists of keywords - the output initially seemed right but turned out to be over counting